# Hiding header, navigation, footer when printing

Tags: navigation, web, printing

When printing the informational content on a web page, I do not want to print the navigation, menu, header, or footer. I would want to include the URL of the page so that I can find it again (and maybe the URLs of external links).

**Is there ever a use case for printing the navigation of a site?**

Comment: This question is off topic to UX because it's about implementation. But you are on the right track.

I'd suggest you ask at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) and check out this article from [Smash Magazine](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/)

Comment: I disagree that it is about implementation - it is about the usability of hiding the navigation when printing. I just included the CSS to show what I am doing. But the Smashing Magazine link is helpful, thank you.

Comment: This is absolutely on-topic. It isn't an implementation question.

Comment: I just removed the CSS example to avoid any confusion :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a mixture of ux and implementation. The ux part is the consideration on behalf of the user to be able to clearly see where this came from (plus other links printed out).

> Optimizing web pages for print is important because we want our sites to be as accessible as possible, no matter the medium. We shouldn’t make assumptions about our users and their behavior. People still print web pages. Just think about articles or blog posts, recipes, contact information, and directions or real estate sites. Someone somewhere will eventually try to print one of the pages you made.

I won't put any css markup here (better handled by stack overflow), but here's a fairly recent article regarding print stylesheets:

**[I totally forgot about print style sheets](https://uxdesign.cc/i-totally-forgot-about-print-style-sheets-f1e6604cfd6)**

It has a section regarding print links out.

Comment: thanks. I know *how* to do a print stylesheet and a print media query, so I promise this is about *whether* to hide the navigation in the print stylesheet.